# concatenate year month date column into one column in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have 4 columns which is dob, date, month, year within a data.table, for instance:

```
dob     | date | month | year

11-02-95|  11  |  2    | 1995

(Chr)   | (Chr)| (Chr) |  (Chr)
```

I want to modify the original dob column by combining date, month and year column

My code is in below and got error:

```
# I filter the NA column in date and month and year
dt[dt$date & dt$month & dt$year, dob := paste(date,month,year, sep = "")]

Error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

expect result:

```
dob       | date | month | year

11-02-1995|  11  |  2    | 1995

(Chr)     | (Chr)| (Chr) |  (Chr)
```

After use the below code:

```
dt[, dob := as.Date(paste(date,month,year, sep = "-"), "%d-%m-%y")]
```

results:

```
dob          | date | month | year

2019-02-11   |  11  |  2    | 1995

(Chr)        | (Chr)| (Chr) |  (Chr)
```

All year change to 2019, but the date and month is correct

Comment: I think you want `!is.na(date) & !is.na(month) & !is.na(year)`?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with dates is difficult. In this case, you have to be careful with the format specifiers:

- `%y` (lower case *y*) denotes year without century (2 digits)
- `%Y` (upper case *Y*) denotes year with century (4 digits)

So,

```
dt[, new_dob1 := as.Date(dob, "%d-%m-%y")] # lower case %y
dt[, new_dob2 := as.Date(paste(date, month, year, sep ="-"), "%d-%m-%Y")] # upper case %Y
dt
```

> ```
>         dob date month year   new_dob1   new_dob2
> 1: 11-02-95   11     2 1995 1995-02-11 1995-02-11
> ```

---

The `lubridate` package aimes at easing the trouble:

```
library(lubridate)
dt[, new_dob1 := dmy(dob)]
dt[, new_dob2 := make_date(year, month, date)]
dt
```

> ```
>         dob date month year   new_dob1   new_dob2
> 1: 11-02-95   11     2 1995 1995-02-11 1995-02-11
> ```

---

The OP has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60627464/concatenate-year-month-date-column-into-one-column-in-r-data-table/60630996#comment107261826_60627534) that `dob` may contain `NA`s. In this case I suggest to
coerce `dob` to `Date` class first, and then to replace any remaining`NA`s:

```
library(lubridate)
dt[, dob := dmy(dob)]
dt[is.na(dob), dob := make_date(year, month, date)]
```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
  "dob     | date | month | year
11-02-95|  11  |  2    | 1995",
  colClasses = "character")
```